# How to add references to multiple "tags"?

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design, foreign-keys, many-to-many

In my database, I have a table for "tags".  So, in my main table, I want to give each item multiple tags.

For example, if my main table is `dog`, I want to add tags for `small` `brown` and `mean`.  But in my `tags` table, I might have 50 possible tags.  Each `dog` can have as many tags if I want.

How do I do that?

I don't really want to create one column for each tag in the main table with a boolean.  Is there a way to specify multiple tags in one field?

(I'm rather not used to working with databases, so this probably sounds stupid.)

In the end, the goal is to be able to get all the dogs that match a particular tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a many-to-many relationship between dogs and tags. You would typically represent that with a bridge table, that references the two other referential tables, that store dogs and tags.

Assuming the following structures for the referential tables:

```
create table dogs (
    dog_id int primary key,
    name text
);

create table tags (
    tag_id int primary key,
    name text
);
```

You would create the bridge table as:

```
create table dogs_tags (
    dog_id int references dogs(dog_id),
    tag_id int references tags(tag_id),
    primary key (dog_id, tag_id)
);
```

Comment: Wait - how will I specify the tags in the dog table?  I would normally add tags to dogs and intuitively do it in the dog table.

Comment: @bgmCoder: you store the tags of each dog in the bridge table, not in the dogs table.

Comment: Okay, that only allows you to match one dog to one tag; I guess I'm supposed to enter the dog again every time I want to tag it?

Comment: @bgmCoder: Yes, you can create as many rows as you want in the bridge table for a given dog.

Comment: Uh, one more thing... can you show me the query string for fetching a dog with three tags, please?  (hee hee - uh, thanks!)  Once I see things like that, I can manipulate and then understand better.  It helps me alot.